# (Iron)Python inheritance constructor issue

Tags: .net, python, inheritance, constructor, ironpython

So I'm trying to make a subclass of DataGridViewColumn, which has both a no-argument constructor, and a constructor that takes one argument, which expects type DataGridViewCell. This is my class:

```
class TableColumn(DataGridViewColumn):
    def __init__(self, string):
        super(TableColumn, self)
        self.Text = string
        self.CellTemplate = DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        self.ReadOnly = True
```

Whenever I try to pass in a string as the argument like such:

```
foo = TableColumn('Name')
```

It always gives me this:

```
TypeError: expected DataGridViewCell, got str
```

So it seems that it's always passing 'string' to the single-argument constructor of the superclass. I've tried replacing super(TableColumn, self) with super(TableColumn,self).`__`init`__`() to be explicitly sure that I want to call the no-argument constructor, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with IronPython, but the __init__() seems like it should be fine. Maybe the whole traceback would be helpful.

Comment: The only thing is the traceback doesn't show me what happens past calling the constructor, so there's no useful information.

Comment: Hmm so it seems that it's an error with Python 2.7 (which the latest version of IronPython uses), which doesn't allow this.

Comment: Python 2.7 definitely allows this. Unless there's something weird about the parent class. But did you mean to call super(TableColumn, self) rather than, say, super(TableColumn, self).__init__()?

Comment: Also, is that TypeError being raised by TableColumn's __init__ method, or from somewhere else?

Comment: I tried this with a generic case: 
'class A:'
'   def __init__(self, arg=''):'
'     pass 

'class B(A):'
'  def __init__(self, string):'
'    super(B,self).__init__()'
'    self.name = string '

Calling B('foo') returns an TypeError albiet because 2.x is weird about new-style classes.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't want to implement `__init__` when deriving from a .NET class; [you need to implement `__new__` instead](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#calling-base-constructor).

```
class TableColumn(DataGridViewColumn):
    def __new__(cls, string):
        DataGridViewColumn.__new__(cls)
        self.Text = string
        self.CellTemplate = DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        self.ReadOnly = True
```

Basically, the constructors of .NET base classes need to be called before the Python subclass' `__init__` (but after `__new__`), which is why you were getting the wrong DataGridViewColumn constructor called.